# Create new security group for redshift and apply using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-redshift, terraform-provider-aws

I'm quite new to Terraform, and struggling with something.

I'm playing around with Redshift for a personal project, and I want to update the inbound security rules for the default security group which is applied to Redshift when it's created.

If I were doing it in AWS Console, I'd be adding a new inbound rule with `Type` being `All Traffic` and `Source` being `Anywhere -IPv4` which adds `0.0.0.0/0`.

Below in `main.tf` I've tried to create a new security group and apply that to Redshift, but I get a `VPC-by-Default customers cannot use cluster security groups` error.

What is it I'm doing wrong?

```
resource "aws_redshift_cluster" "redshift" {
  cluster_identifier = "redshift-cluster-pipeline"
  skip_final_snapshot = true terraform destroy
  master_username    = "awsuser"
  master_password    = var.db_password
  node_type          = "dc2.large"
  cluster_type       = "single-node"
  publicly_accessible = "true"
  iam_roles = [aws_iam_role.redshift_role.arn]
  cluster_security_groups = [aws_redshift_security_group.redshift-sg.name]
}

resource "aws_redshift_security_group" "redshift-sg" {
  name = "redshift-sg"
  ingress {
    cidr = "0.0.0.0/0"
    }
```

Comment: Could you try to create `aws_redshift_security_group` before creating the `aws_redshift_cluster`?

And any update when you run `terraform plan`?

Comment: Looks okay. Plan runs fine. I think I'm just missing something or not understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/redshift_security_group) for the Terraform resource `aws_redshift_security_group` states:

> Creates a new Amazon Redshift security group. You use security groups
> to control access to non-VPC clusters

The error message you are receiving is clearly staging that you are using the wrong type of security group, and you need to use a VPC security group instead. Once you create the appropriate VPC security group, you would set it in the `aws_redshift_cluster` resource via the `vpc_security_group_ids` property.

Comment: What's the different between a cluster and vpc security group? I did find the `aws_security_group` resource but wasn't sure how to set it up for my purposes.

Comment: Back before everything was required to use a VPC, you had separate security groups for things like RDS and Redshift. Now that everything is required to be in a VPC everything uses VPC security groups.